# What is the difference between sanitize_text_field() and wp_filter_nohtml_kses()?

Tags: theme-customizer, sanitization

I need to sanitize some custom settings added with the Customize API, namely some simple text fields.

Other data types have some dedicated functions, i.e. email addresses should use `sanitize_email()`, URL's have `esc_url_raw()` and so on.

But with simple text fields, I'm not really sure if I must use [`sanitize_text_field()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_text_field/) or [`wp_filter_nohtml_kses()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_filter_nohtml_kses/), even after reading their descriptions in the Code Reference they seem to be very similar and I don' really know how to choose one of them.

Intuitively, I would go with `sanitize_text_field()`, but some online guides ([this](https://maddisondesigns.com/2017/05/the-wordpress-customizer-a-developers-guide-part-1/) and [this](https://divpusher.com/blog/wordpress-customizer-sanitization-examples/#text)) seem to suggest that `wp_filter_nohtml_kses()` is what should be used instead.

**What are the exact differences between these two functions, and how can I choose one of them in this situation?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### What Do They Do?

`wp_filter_nohtml_kses` strips all HTML from a string, that's it. It does it via the `wp_kses` function and it expects slashed data, here's its implementation:

```php
function wp_filter_nohtml_kses( $data ) {
    return addslashes( wp_kses( stripslashes( $data ), 'strip' ) );
}
```

`sanitize_text_field` on the other hand does more than that, the doc says:

> - Checks for invalid UTF-8,
> - Converts single < characters to entities
> - Strips all tags
> - Removes line breaks, tabs, and extra whitespace
> - Strips octets

Specificially the point of `sanitize_text_field` is to sanitize text fields. Since you want to sanitize a text field, you should use `sanitize_text_field`.

#### So Why Does One Article Recommend `wp_filter_nohtml_kses`?

**It doesn't.**

The author correctly recognised the variable may contain HTML, and searched for a function to do just that, and found `wp_filter_nohtml_kses`.

*However this is neither the best function for this job, or the appropriate one.* `sanitize_text_field` targets the actual problem, that the field needs sanitising, and does a more than strip out tags.

The author could easily have chosen `wp_strip_all_tags`, but should have gone for `sanitize_text_field`.

Which brings us to the main points:

1. Not all guides are correct
2. When faced with a choice between 2 functions, pick the one that literally says what you want to do, not the obscure one
3. `wp_filter_nohtml_kses` would not have protected against octal characters, and other things that `sanitize_text_field` does, but perhaps the author was unaware of those  attack vectors?
4. Some of the things `sanitize_text_field` does are less about security and more about cleanliness, e.g. stripping extra whitespace

#### Escaping vs Sanitising

> URL's have esc_url_raw() and so on.

Not quite, `esc_url_raw` is an escaping function, escaping is not sanitisation! Though this is a rare exception where it can be used as a sanitising function

- Sanitising data cleans it
- Validating data confirms it
- Escaping data secures it

Sanitise and validate on input, escape on output.

Another way to think of it, is like a gameshow:

- Sanitising is the cleanup they do to get you ready for TV
- Validation is the judge at the end of the round who checks that you did what you were asked
- Escaping is the giant wall with the shaped hole you have to fit through or it'll push you off the ledge

For example, consider this value: `" bananas@test.com <b>hello!</b> "`

- we sanitize with `sanitize_email`, eliminating trailing spaces, etc, giving us `bananas@test.combhellob`
- we can validate it with `validate_email` to check if it is indeed an email
- At this point we can process the input

Some time passes...

- now we need to output the data, so we escape it
- `echo esc_url( 'mailto:'.$email );`

Now we get a `mailto` link with an email, **it will always be a link**. There is no dithering about it should be a link, it can be a link, it's supposed to be a link, etc. It is guaranteed to be a link, there is now certainty. No assumptions need to be made.

Lets say that `$email` was sanitised and validated, and saved, yet the sites database was mangled or modified during a hack. Now, `$email` contains a JS bitcoin miner! Or it did until `esc_url` mangled it into an email. The email isn't usable, but it has the format of an email.

For this reason, escaping is only done on output, uses an escaping function appropriate for the exected output, not the data ( `esc_attr` for html attributes, `esc_html` for text, `esc_url` for URLs, and so on ). Escaping is also done at the latest possible moment, closest to output. This way escaped data can't be modified after its been escaped, and there's no confusion about when something was escaped that might cause double escaping.

For this reason, avoid adding HTML to a variable then echoing it at the end, or passing around complex HTML fragments in variables. You have no way to know if they're safe or not

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, I really appreciate the time and effort you spent on this <3. ABout `esc_url_raw`, the Codex explicitly says to use this instead of `sanitize_url`, which is deprecated [link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_url/)

Comment: then that would be the exception to the rule, just know it's an escaping function originally. Similar to if you want to escape a string but preserve some tags, such as hyperlinks and bold, `wp_kses` and `wp_kses_post` can be used for that, but they're not technically escaping functions.

Answer (score 1):

The key difference is `sanitize_text_field()`:

- Checks for invalid UTF-8
- Converts single `<` characters to entities
- Strips all tags
- Removes line breaks, tabs, and extra whitespace
- Strips octets

...and is designed primarily for user input (e.g. `GET/POST/COOKIE`).

Meanwhile `wp_filter_nohtml_kses()` *just* strips all HTML from a text string. Worth noting that it expects the string param you pass [to be slashed](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2016/04/06/rest-api-slashed-data-in-wordpress-4-4-and-4-5/).

As for which one you use, tradition says "sanitize on input, escape on output". Which would suggest `sanitize_text_field` in your case, and use `wp_filter_nohtml_kses` (or similar) when you output it.

Having said that, if you never want users to be able to save HTML in these text fields, you should strip it out on input too - but *always* use `sanitize_text_field` (or similar) beforehand.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!